# Documentation URL of os module

Tags: python, pycharm, documentation, python-os

I'm trying to crack the URL format for Python's `os` module for use in PyCharm's documentation window.

My attempt so far:

```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#{element.qname}
```

but I'm having trouble displaying documentations such as:

```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path
```

What's the right format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before addressing the URL hack, it should be mentioned that **the deciding setting of how documentation is shown** is the [*"Render external documentation for `stdlib`"*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-python-integrated-tools.html) setting. You can configure it by going to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Python Integrated Tools` `>` `Docstrings` `>` `Render external documentation for stdlib` as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

1. **If you enable** the "*Render external documentation for `stdlib`*" setting (and have internet access), the IDE will automatically retrieve standard library docs from `https://docs.python.org/{python.version}/library/{module.name}.html#{element.qname}`. The Python version is automatically determined from the [Python interpreter configured for the Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter), so that's the version of the documentation shown for the file you have opened in the editor.

[image]

See how this corresponds to the online documentation:

[image]

2. **If you disable** the "*Render external documentation for `stdlib`*" setting (or don't have internet access), the IDE will show the docstrings of its integrated stub files.

[image]

Having said that, the [documentation tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/documentation-tool-window.html) **does not require configuring the URL for standard library modules** (e.g. for the `os`, `sys`, etc...) contrary to how it's necessary for other libraries' [External Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-reference-information.html#configure-python-external-documentation). In fact, there is no option in the IDE settings to change the address for standard library modules.

> What's the right format?

The complete format would be:

```
https://docs.python.org/{python.version}/library/{module.name}.html#{element.qname}
```

> crack the URL format for Python's `os` module for use in PyCharm's documentation window.

This can be done, but it is limited to specific modules. It can not be done for the whole standard library because the base `Module Name` field would have to be left empty and in that case the IDE will ignore the setting.

[image]

If you use the hack for a specific module, **the IDE will show the docstrings in the documentation tool window (like in example 2)** but if you click the external link it will open the browser in the address configured in the external documentation. See the screenshot:

[image]

So the hack has limited usefulness.

The hack can be used with offline docs if you [download the Python HTML documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/download.html) (but it would still be limited to only showing documentation like in example 2). In that use case the correct way to write the URL would depend on OS/Shell/Browser, for Windows/CMD/Firefox you could use the below URL but there's no way to escape the hash `#` sign so the anchor won't work, but you'll be taken to the documentation page.

```
file:///C:/directory_name/library/{module.name}.html#{element.qname}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JerryAjay FTR, one of the hardest answers I've written on SO. I had postponed trying this hack several times because getting a systematic overview of all the IDE quirks it involves was mind boggling... If you check the PyCharm documentation all these behaviors aren't clearly explained and the user has to trial&error his way through the IDE behavior. (Frustrating errors not included in the post...)

Comment: Yes! I agree. Once again, thanks a lot! Not all libraries are well path'ed. Some well written ones follow a clean structure: `https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/{element.qname}`  :-)